# How to query a specific period during a day over the last year

Tags: mysql

I would like to select a specific period during the day (15 mins) and then I simply want to fetch historic data for each day for the past year. I simply dont know where to put `INTERVAL 1 DAY` in MySQL. I want to get data from (2012-10-15 to 2013-10-15).

So here is my sample code:

```
select *, FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp/1000000000) 
FROM pulsars
WHERE timestamp between UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-15 02:00:00')*1e9 
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-10-15 02:15:00')*1e9 
AND name = 'GEMINGA'
ORDER by timestamp
LIMIT 0,100000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [...]
from pulsars 
where time(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) between time('02:00:00') and time('02:15:00')
and name = 'GEMINGA'
and timestamp between unix_timestamp('2012-10-15') and unix_timestamp('2013-10-15')
group by date(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp));
```

the `time()` function will extract only the daytime from you timestamp. I convert the dates into unix_timestamp in the where clause because i guess that timestamp has an index and thus the query will be faster. Grouping by day gives one row for each day. Aggregate functions in the select you have to do yourself as i don't know your data.

If you ant to select each day separatly ditch the group by  and use `timestamp between unix_timestamp(select_date) and unix_timestamp(select_date + interval 1 day)` for each day.